# Como fazer uma img embaçar ao passar o mouse sobre ela?

Tags: css, html5

Estou tendo dificuldade com este elemento do site que estou tentando montar para escola, se não for possível que um site realize esta função me avisem por favor.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque está a pedir para fazermos o trabalho de casa pelo OP.

Comment: Meu trabalho é fazer um site de biologia, isso era só um elemento do site que eu tava com dificuldade em arrumar, mas blz, eu me viro

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser visto [aqui](https://jsbin.com/dapigaciqu/edit?html,css,output),

**Update:** Obrigado Diego Schmidt pela observação, conforme consta na [documentação da Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms530752(v=vs.85).aspx).

> **Observação:** A partir do Windows Internet Explorer 9, esse recurso foi obsoleto. A partir do Internet Explorer 10, esse recurso foi
>   removido e não deve mais ser usado.

```css
    img {
      transition: .3s all;
      border-radius: 3px;
    }
    .bg:hover img {
      -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
      filter: blur(2px);
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="bg">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/200" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Só uma observação, a função filter não funciona no IE.